# Are tags appropriate on "outside looking in" questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a question about static analysis and AOT compilation of CLI code.  The question was inspired by a limitation in a particular development system - Xamarin.

Because Xamarin was thus mentioned non-trivially, I had considered including the [xamarin](/questions/tagged/xamarin) tag, however thought better of it on the grounds that the question is not actually about *working with* Xamarin - it's instead a question of its design rationale/justification, which really extends to any system like it.  Basically its an "outside looking in" sort of question.  (The actual question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906360/static-analysis-of-virtual-generic-method-calls).)

An experienced SO user subsequently added the [xamarin](/questions/tagged/xamarin) tag, which made me wonder exactly what it means to tag a question as such.

I would have thought the tag means "my question is about working with Xamarin," but would it also generally be taken to possibly mean "my question is about how a system like Xamarin would be engineered?"

On one hand adding the tag might interest technology developers in the question, but on the other hand it might preclude qualified answerers.  For instance, someone who doesn't develop for mobile might have ignored tags such as [xamarin](/questions/tagged/xamarin) but nevertheless might be intimately knowledgeable in the inner workings of the CLI and would probably be *very* qualified to answer.

Comment: It depends whether or not you need to know anything about Xamarin to answer the question. If the question is 100% answerable without *any* knowledge about Xamarin, the tag probably shouldn't be there.